# Change table (spliced image) onclick

Tags: php, jquery, html-table

I'm new to jquery so i'm sorry if this is simple. I have looked around and have not found anything that does what I want. I have 3 tables which are spliced images. each table has an id. when someone clicks on an image in a table I want the table to change to a different one which also has an id. I have no idea how to do this. I hope this makes sense.

I want to be able to change the entire table instead of changing each individual image ideally.

```
<table id="norm">
<tr><td>
<!-- images -->
<!-- clickable image -->
<!-- images-->
</td></tr>
</table>


<table id="chang1">
<tr><td>
<!-- images -->
<!-- clickable image -->
<!-- images-->
</td></tr>
</table>


<table id="chang2">
<tr><td>
<!-- images -->
<!-- clickable image -->
<!-- images-->
</td></tr>
</table>
```

This is what I want to do but in PHP:

```
if($_GET['imtype']=='norm'){
  //show id='norm' table
}else{
  if($_GET['imtype']=='chang1'){
    //show id='chang1' table
  }else{
    if($_GET['imtype']=='chang2'){
      //show id='chang2' table
    }  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for the changing part

```
$('#chang1').show();
$('#oldtable').hide();
```

This would do the trick but for the conditions I did'nt quite get what you wanna do.
Which images should redirect to which table?

Then this would help

```
function ShowTable(tableId)
{
    $('table').hide();
    $('#' + tableId).show();
}
```

And on your links you just put href="javascript:ShowTable('yourtableid')"

Comment: each image should have 3 links which would load 1 of the 3 tables depending on which link is clicked. so id="norm" table has 3 image links in it that lead to id="norm" table, id="chang1" table, and id="chang2" table. id="chang1" table and id="chang2" table have the same thing. Does that make more sense?